# Creating a maze game where the game resets if you hit traps/walls and finishes when you hit a different color

Tags: javascript, game, collision

Here’s my code, the traps are the slightly visible squares. The user controls a red square (with arrow keys) and cannot touch the walls or traps or else the game resets. Additionally, if the user touches the green line, the game ends.

Code:

---

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Maze Game</title>
</head>
<body>
<header> </header>
<nav> </nav>
<section>
<div>
<canvas id="canvas" width="907" height="907">
This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
</canvas>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas;
var ctx;
var dx = 5;
var dy = 5;
var x = 345;
var y = 135;
var WIDTH = 907;
var HEIGHT = 907;
var img = new Image();
var collision = 0;
//set minutes
        var mins = 2;
        //calculate the seconds
        var secs = mins * 60;
        //countdown function is evoked when page is loaded
        function countdown() {
            setTimeout('Decrement()', 60);
        }
        //Decrement function decrement the value.
        function Decrement() {
            if (document.getElementById) {
                minutes = document.getElementById("minutes");
                seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
                //if less than a minute remaining
                //Display only seconds value.
                if (seconds < 59) {
                    seconds.value = secs;
                }
                //Display both minutes and seconds
                //getminutes and getseconds is used to
                //get minutes and seconds

                else {
                    minutes.value = getminutes();
                    seconds.value = getseconds();
                }
                //when less than a minute remaining
                //colour of the minutes and seconds
                //changes to red
                if (mins < 1) {
                    minutes.style.color = "red";
                    seconds.style.color = "red";
                }
                //if seconds becomes zero,
                //then page alert time up
                if (mins < 0) {
                    alert('Times up!');
                    minutes.value = 0;
                    seconds.value = 0;
                                        document.location.reload();
    clearInterval(interval); // Needed for Chrome to end game
                }
                //if seconds > 0 then seconds is decremented
                else {
                    secs--;
                    setTimeout('Decrement()', 1000);
} }
}
        function getminutes() {
            //minutes is seconds divided by 60, rounded down
            mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
            return mins;
}
        function getseconds() {
            //take minutes remaining (as seconds) away
            //from total seconds remaining
            return secs - Math.round(mins * 60);
}
function rect(x,y,w,h) {
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(x,y,w,h);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
}
function clear() {
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
function init() {
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
img.src = "canvas.png";

return setInterval(draw, 10);
}
function doKeyDown(evt){
switch (evt.keyCode) {
case 38:  /* Up arrow was pressed */
if (y - dy > 0){
y -= dy;
clear();
checkcollision();
if (collision == 1){
y += dy;
collision = 0;
}
}
break;
case 40:  /* Down arrow was pressed */
if (y + dy < HEIGHT ){
y += dy;
clear();
checkcollision();
if (collision == 1){
y -= dy;
collision = 0;
}
}
break;
case 37:  /* Left arrow was pressed */
if (x - dx > 0){
x -= dx;
clear();
checkcollision();
if (collision == 1){
x += dx;
collision = 0;
}
}
break;
case 39:  /* Right arrow was pressed */
if ((x + dx < WIDTH)){
x += dx;
clear();
checkcollision();
if (collision == 1){
x -= dx;
collision = 0;
}
}
break;
}
}
function checkcollision() {
var imgd = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 15, 15);
var pix = imgd.data;

for (var i = 0; n = pix.length, i < n; i += 4) {
if (pix[i] == 0) {
collision = 1;
}
} }
function draw() {
clear();
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
rect(x, y, 15,15);
}
init();
window.addEventListener('keydown',doKeyDown,true);
</script>
<body onload="countdown();">
    <div>
        Time Left ::
        <input id="minutes" type="text" style="width: 16px;
             border: none; font-size: 30px;
            font-weight: bold; color: black;"><font size="30"> :
                        </font>
        <input id="seconds" type="text" style="width: 40px;
                        border: none; font-size: 30px;font-weight: bold; color: black;">
 </section>
<aside> </aside>
<footer> </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Please help me figure this out!!!

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview@SE. As shown, the code file contains extraneous contents after the closing `</html>`. [To the best of your knowledge: Does this code work?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Trying it as-is will result in an error, but substituting a temporary image makes the game run. Without proper markers it does not do anything useful tho. An actual image to load would be useful.

Comment: Sigh, this looks a really cool question, but if you want good feedback, we should be able to run it, and right now it wont because of the image requirement. Note to vote-closers; there is enough context.

Comment: Sorry guys, I totally forgot about the canvas.png. I added it so you can save it

Comment: The HTML is broken. There are two opening `body` tags.

Comment: Might I suggest using https://jsfiddle.net/? It'll help others run your code & help yourself ensure you're including enough details for others to run the project.

Answer (score 3):

From a lengthy review;

- Clean up tags that are not used (doubles like `body` or unused like `nav`)
- Use a beautifier like https://beautifier.io/
- Make sure you close your tags properly (the closing tag of the time section was missing)
- Leverage css styling, inline styling does not scale, and HTML is not the right place to style!
- document.getElementById is supported since IE 5.5, not need to check for `if (document.getElementById)`

  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById
- Your starting image should probably not have a red square ;)
- I prefer naming to be either Spartan (one letter) or spelled out, no middle ground like `evt`
- You should use `e.preventDefault();` to prevent the browser window from trying to act on the key arrow events
- Redesign your code to have fewer globals, like `collision` which is only set in 1 place, and checked in 1 place
- 15 is a repeated magical constant, it should be a variable
- JavaScript uses lowerCamelCase, so `getseconds` -> `getSeconds`
- Using `input` tags for the minutes/seconds is unorthdox, since they are  not input fields
- `secs` was an unfortunate name, `secondsLeft` might have been better, I went for `timer`
- The movement code contained a lot of pasting, you could make it data structure driven
- The checking for mines and the green line end of the game is not implemented..

Bigger topic, do not use the UI to store state, I repeat, do not use the UI to store state. You are counting on the black lines in the image as walls, I had to downsample the image because an answer can only 64K long (and the full image is 72K) Because of this, none of the detection logic worked any more. Using the UI to store state will always bite you, when you least expect it. Yes, I am still bitter.

I wrote a counter proposal 'that works', it still has many globals, but at least in this state I would be willing to maintain the code.

```js
const minutes = document.getElementById("minutes");
const seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

let ctx;
const img = new Image();
//Dimensions
const WIDTH = canvas.clientWidth;
const HEIGHT = canvas.clientHeight;
//Player start position
let x = 170;
let y = 60;
const playerSize = 15;

//The timer starts at 2 minutes
let timer = 2 * 60;

//Decrement function decrement the value.
function countDown() {
  //Calculate label values
  minutes.textContent =  ~~(timer/60); //Fancy math trick
  seconds.textContent = timer % 60;

  //when less than a minute remains, change to red
  if (timer < 60) {
    minutes.style.color = "red";
    seconds.style.color = "red";
  }
  //alert if the time is up
  //then page alert time up
  if (timer < 0) {
    alert('Times up!');
    minutes.value = 0;
    seconds.value = 0;
    //Not sure about this.. at all..
    document.location.reload();
    clearInterval(interval); // Needed for Chrome to end game <- Not sure I believe you
  } else { //if seconds > 0 then keep counting down
    timer--;
    setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
  }
}

//I almost dropped this, you only use this once 
//I assume you plan to do more with this
function rect(x, y, w, h) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(x, y, w, h);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}

//init() is called from body.onload in HTML
function init() {
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    
    //This is set with base64 encoding below
    //Because otherwise ctx.getImageData will throw a security exception when running on stackoverflow
    //In real life, with the image and source on the same host, there is no need for base64 shenanigans
    //img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/57Vay.gif";

    //Moved this here, it's part of the initialization.
    window.addEventListener('keydown', doKeyDown, true);
    
    //This draws every 10 milliseconds, so 100fps, not sure this is needed
    setInterval(draw, 10);
    
    //Start the countdown
    setTimeout(countDown, 60);
}

function draw() {
    clear();
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    rect(x, y, playerSize, playerSize);
}

function clear() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

function doKeyDown(e) {
    const moveSize = 5;
    const moves = {
      37: {dx: -moveSize, dy: 0}, /* Left arrow was pressed */
      38: {dy: -moveSize, dx: 0}, /* Up arrow was pressed */
      39: {dx:  moveSize, dy: 0}, /* Right arrow was pressed */
      40: {dy:  moveSize, dx: 0}  /* Down arrow was pressed */
    }

    if(moves[e.keyCode]){
      const move = moves[e.keyCode];
      x += move.dx;
      y += move.dy;
      clear();
      if (hasCollision()) {
        x -= move.dx;
        y -= move.dy;
      }
      e.preventDefault();
    }
}

/* This only checks for the walls, not for the exit or the mines*/
function hasCollision() {
  //checkingCollision = true;
  const imageData = ctx.getImageData(x, y, playerSize, playerSize);
  const pixels = imageData.data;
  const n = pixels.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < n; i += 4) {
    //Because black lines have rgb code r0,g0,b0 
    //And we have no other color that has zero as the r value
    //If we had, then this check would have to be more cumbersome!
    
    //Update: downscaling the image must have added some quite black, but not exactly black images
    //So I changed the check to pixels[i] < 100
    if (pixels[i] < 100 ) {
      return true;
    }
  }
}


//Obviously, this does not belong here.. it should be in init()
//However the StackOverflow editor is suffering from this huge string, so I've put it at the end to put it and myself out of our misery
img.setAttribute('src','data:image/png;base64,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');
```

```css
#minutes {width: 16px;border: none;font-weight: bold; color: black}
#seconds {width: 40px;border: none;font-weight: bold; color: black}
.bigFont {font-size: 30px}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Maze Game</title>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
    <section>
        <div>
            <canvas id="canvas" width="454" height="454">
                This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
            </canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="bigFont">
            Time Left :: <span id="minutes" type="text">2</span> : <span id="seconds" type="text" style="">0</span>
        </div>
    </section>
    <aside> </aside>
    <footer> </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: One small remark: "countdown" can be spelled as a single word, so writing it with a lower case "d" is fine IMO.

Comment: 'Fortunately' there was a pattern of that, fixed!